# Why does QFileDialog use slash instead of backslash?

Tags: python, operating-system, windows-10, pyside, qfiledialog

**Why "\" and "/" are mixed?**

`os.getcwd()` emits backslash string.

On the other hand, `QFileDialog` emits forward slash string.

Why?

**Example**

Please execute this sample code.

```
from PySide import QtGui
from PySide import QtCore
import sys
import os

class DirectoryPrinter(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DirectoryPrinter,self).__init__(parent=None)

        self.filedialog_pushbutton = QtGui.QPushButton("filedialog",self)
        self.connect(self.filedialog_pushbutton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.filename_getter)

    def filename_getter(self):
        print("from os.getcwd()",os.getcwd())
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Select your file",os.path.expanduser("~"))[0]
        print("from QFileDialog",filename)


def main():
    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(22,e)
    directoryprinter = DirectoryPrinter()
    directoryprinter.show()

    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Result (on my occasion)**

from `os.getcwd()`: `J:\`

from `QFileDialog`: `C:/Users/******/setup.py`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `QFileDialog` [uses forward slashes regardless of OS. This makes it easier to write path handling code](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40381-QFiledialog-returns-forward-slashes-instead-of-backslashes).

You can use [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to converts forward slashes to backward slashes in a path on Windows.

Comment: In fact , I have found out this result from PySide Documentation,QDir class.But your information has great amount of knowledge and very useful.thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design decision on Qt's part, while Python uses the system's conventions for paths*.

If you want to convert by using Qt itself, you can use:

```py
QtCore.QDir.toNativeSeparators(filename)
```

*Note: Python uses the system's conventions, some functions handle forward slashes on Windows. If you're building your own paths in Python, I suggest you take a look at [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which is in Python's standard library.

**Tip: If building with pathlib, the simplest option is to **not use** Path.joinpath() when joining the directory with the filename. Use slashes as operators instead:

```py
from pathlib import Path
dirpath = Path(r'Avoid\Using\Hardcoded\Paths')
filename = dirpath / "basename.ext"
```